# C# WFA - Choose a client name from a list in another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

I'm developing a Windows Form Application for a book seller in my school.

I have a Form for Clients and Books, where I can view the list of clients/books in a DataGridView, Insert new ones to the list, modify, and delete them.

For the Sales form, I need to specify the name of the Client and the Book.

I was thinking on putting a Textbox with a button, and when I click the button, I'll show another window from which I can access the clients/book list, select one from the list and fill the Textbox with his name, or I can directly add a new client, if needed.

Is this possible, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
btnClients_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ClientsForms form = new ClientsForms())
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxClient.Text = form.ClientName;
        }
    }
}
```

ClientsForms is your form with Clients. It should have public property ClientName or whatever you need. This property should be set base on value selected in DataGridView.